# sql index same column two directions for traversing window functions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying use windowing functions to group records close to each other (within the same partition) into sequential groups. There's probably a better way to solve the problem, but right now what I would like to try is running too slow to be useful. It involves an order by on the select:

```
order by person_id, rollup_class, rollup_concept_id, exp_num
```

and another order by in the window function:

```
lead(days_from_latest) over (partition by person_id, rollup_class, rollup_concept_id 
order by exp_num DESC)
```

Because I have that last column (`exp_num`) ordered in opposite directions, the query takes forever. I even have two indexes on the table to handle the two directions:

```
create index deeIdx on results.drug_exposure_extra (person_id,rollup_class, rollup_concept_id,
    exp_num);
create index deeIdx2 on results.drug_exposure_extra (person_id,rollup_class,rollup_concept_id,
    exp_num desc);
```

But that doesn't help. So I'm trying one that orders exp_num in both directions:

```
create index deeIdx3 on results.drug_exposure_extra (person_id,rollup_class,rollup_concept_id, 
     exp_num, exp_num desc);
```

Does that even make sense? When the index finally finishes building, if it solves the problem, I'll answer my own question...

Nope.

Even with all three indexes, if the two order bys (in select and in over clause) go the same direction, the query runs super fast, if they go opposite directions the query runs super slow. So, at this point I guess I should explain my use case better and ask for ideas for a better approach.

I've got drug exposure records (this is for a cool open-source project http://www.ohdsi.org/, btw), and when a person has drug exposures that begin less than N days from the end of any previous exposure, it should be combined with the earlier ones into a single 'era'. Whenever there is a gap of more than N days, a new era begins.

Over the course of composing this question, it turns out I solved it. It raises some interesting issues, though, so I'll post it and answer it below.

Answer (score 0):

Like asking a doctor, "It hurts when I move my arm like this, what should I do?" the answer is obviously, "Don't move your arm like that." So -- don't try to make windowing functions proceed in a different order from the main query (or probably from each other) -- there's probably a better solution.

Early in working on this I had somehow convinced myself that it would be easier to aggregate eras relative to their ending records rather than their starting records, but that was where I went wrong.

So the expression that gives me the era number I want looks like this:

```
    sum(case when exp_num = 1 or days_from_latest > 30 then 1 else 0 end)
      over (partition by person_id, rollup_class, rollup_concept_id
            order by exp_num)
        as era_num
```

Explanation: if it's the patient's first exposure to the drug (well, the combination of rollup_class and rollup_concept_id in this case), then that's the beginning of a drug era. It's also the beginning of a drug era if the exposure is more than N days from any earlier exposure. *(This point is what makes it a little complicated: say exposure 1 starts at day 1 and is 60 days, exposure 2 starts at day 20 and is 10 days, exposure 3 starts at day 70: it's 40 days after the end of the most recent exposure, 2, which would put it in a new era, but it's only 10 days after exposure 1, which puts it in the same era with 1 and 2.)* So, for each record that starts an era the case statement gives us a 1, the rest get 0s. Then we sum that, partitioning over the same partition we used in an earlier query to establish the exp_num, and order by exp_num. I could have specified the rows to sum explicitly by adding `rows between unbounded preceding and current row`, but that's the default behavior anyway. So the era number increments only at the beginning of new eras.

Here is a much simplified example in response to gordon-linoff's comment below.

```
create table junk_numbers (x int);
insert into junk_numbers values (1),(2),(3),(5),(7),(9),(10),(15),(20),(25),(26),(28),(30);

-- break into series with gaps of at least 1
select x, gap, 1+sum(case when gap > 1 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by x) as series_num
from (
    select x, x - lag(x) over (order by x) as gap
    from junk_numbers
    ) as x_and_gaps
order by x;

  x  | gap | series_num
  ----+-----+------------
   1 |     |          1
   2 |   1 |          1
   3 |   1 |          1
   5 |   2 |          2
   7 |   2 |          3
   9 |   2 |          4
  10 |   1 |          4
  15 |   5 |          5
  20 |   5 |          6
  25 |   5 |          7
  26 |   1 |          7
  28 |   2 |          8
  30 |   2 |          9

-- same query but bigger gaps:
select x, gap, 1+sum(case when gap > 4 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by x) as series_num
from (
    select x, x - lag(x) over (order by x) as gap
    from junk_numbers
    ) as x_and_gaps
order by x;


x  | gap | series_num
----+-----+------------
 1 |     |          1
 2 |   1 |          1
 3 |   1 |          1
 5 |   2 |          1
 7 |   2 |          1
 9 |   2 |          1
10 |   1 |          1
15 |   5 |          2
20 |   5 |          3
25 |   5 |          4
26 |   1 |          4
28 |   2 |          4
30 |   2 |          4
```

Comment: You should probably ask another question with sample data and desired results.  There might be other solutions to solving this problem, solutions that you might not otherwise think of.

Comment: I'm not sure if it merits another question, but I just assembled the data and will add what you suggest to my answer -- much simplified from my real-life example but capturing the problem.